# Where to Download java-ee.jar?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jar

Where does the Jar file come from?  I expected it to be either a part of the JDK or Eclipse.  That expectation proved to be wrong.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Sun/Oracle is providing a **java-ee.jar** - which contains only the Java EE APIs and does not contain any method bodies - that you can use to **compile** against it (from the java.net maven repository):

- For Java EE 5: http://download.java.net/maven/1/javaee/jars/javaee-api-5.jar
- For Java EE 6: http://download.java.net/maven/2/javax/javaee-api/6.0/javaee-api-6.0.jar

If you want to **execute** some Java EE code, you'll need a Java EE application server, they provide an implementation of the Java EE APIs. For example, for Java EE 6, there is [GlassFish](http://glassfish.java.net/).

Comment: How can i add the java-ee dependency in my pom?

Comment: @Kayser: You should typically be adding the dependency as a provided dependency in your POM:  `<dependency>  <groupId>javax</groupId>  
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>  <version>6.0</version>   <scope>provided</scope>  </dependency>`  or  `<dependency>   <groupId>javax.j2ee</groupId>  <artifactId>j2ee</artifactId>   <version>1.4</version>  <scope>provided</scope>  </dependency>`

Answer (score 8):

if you want javaee-api-7.jar, use maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

or you can [download from here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/7.0)

Comment: This is the correct and recommended solution according to the best practices. Simple and functional. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Download Glassfish or JBOSS or another Java EE app server.  They all have it.

Comment: It’s better to include the dependency as suggested in other answers, then you can swap between Glassfish, TomCat, JBoss without having to check your code is compatible.

Comment: No, it'll be a problem if the app server includes the JAR and there's a conflict.  Better yet - don't use Java EE anymore.  Go with Spring Boot.  It's almost 2018.  Java EE is dead.