# I can't compile my servlet code

Tags: java

I am having big problems compiling java servlets. As far as I can see, I've done everything I need to do, I've installed Tomcat 7 correctly, and Tomcat is working. As I understand, I need to add servlet.jar package to my classpath.

I've done this, by editing the classpath environment variables:

```
CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\servlet-api.jar
```

Unfortunately, still no luck, I can't compile java servlets, and I am still get warnings about missing symbols for `javax.servlets.`

I am using Window 7. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you compiling? from command prompt?

Comment: I'm sure the compiler doesn't just say: "I can't compile that". It comes with a specific error message, which refers to the lines of code that don't compile. Show us the code, and show us the error message. It's meaningful, and is intended to be read. Also, you shouldn't set the CLASSPATH like that. Pass it as a `-cp` option to javac.

Comment: yes, what is the error/exceptions.. please show us.

Comment: If compiler complains something like `can not find javax.servlet`, this is sure it can not find the right jar files, you need to set it correctly. or use can use a `.bat` file to write a script with the classpath and call it on `cmd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat already comes with Servlet related stuff jar files. You don't need to worry about them. You have make them available for your application to compile by adding those in your classpath. But not including into the application build.

If your compiler complains about `javax.servlets.` so you are missing the Java EE jar in your classpath. You need to add the Java EE jar file to your classpath (the application classpath). You can download them following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358220/where-can-i-download-j2ee-jar-from). But make sure you do not include them into your build.