# Getting error "stateless cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: jakarta-ee

I'm using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers (Kepler).

I'm getting the error "stateless cannot be resolved to a type". I think I need javaee.jar.

Is this true? Where do I get this JAR file? Where do I install it on my computer?

I am new to Java EE so please provide as much details as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need javaee.jar, which is to be included in the classpath.

To get the jar refer this [stackoverflow question--> to get the jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358220/where-can-i-download-java-ee-jar-from)

And refer this as a starter to get clear your doubts about the java-ee environment and deployment [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/usingexamples.htm#GFIUD)

Hope it helps.