# Which version is latest for Sun/Oracle provided javaee-api-xx.jar and download of latest version >7.0

Tags: java

I am looking which version is latest and from where to download it.I know the already answered link [Where to Download java-ee.jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358220/where-to-download-java-ee-jar) but here I am looking > 7.0 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java EE 7.0 is the latest version of Java EE.  You won't find Java EE 8.0 API jar files<sup>1, 2</sup> because the [Java EE 8.0 JSR](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=366) has not been finalized yet.

---

<sup>1 - At this point in time, you can possibly obtain API jars if you have contacts with "inside knowledge".  However those jars aren't definitive at this point in time.</sup>

<sup>2 - Obviously, this answer will be incorrect at some point in the future.  Maybe Q3 2016 if they stick to the proposed timeline.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can see all the versions [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22javax%22%20AND%20a%3A%22javaee-api%22) and download which ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

For now the latest is 7.0 . You can find links in thread you linked.

Or to add dependancy:
http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax%7Cjavaee-api%7C7.0%7Cjar