# Do i need to install java ee7 to develop web application if i have se 8.45

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm new to java web application and just followed some courses on servlets and jsp.
But now i'm starting on a new course where i should learning the basics of spring. Where they notice i should download java ee.  but everything worked without installing Java ee on the previous course.

I know these are silly questions but i can't find a proper answer...

Some questions.

From the site of oracle: The Java EE 7 SDK Update 1 or Java EE 7 Web Profile SDK Update 1 is extracted into a new glassfish4 directory under your current directory.

How can i download java ee7 without the glassfish server so i can deploy the web application on a tomcat or wildfly server?

If i create web application should i use java ee 7 as external libary instead of se 8.45 .

Do i need to install new windows environment variables for java ee7. like JAVA_HOME for se?

Or don't i need java ee for spring web application ?

Comment: Java EE is an umbrella specification, covering many specifications (servlets, JSP, JPA, CDI, etc. Specifications are just documents, and some jars containing standard annotations, interfaces and classes. All those jars are bundled in application servers supporting the specification (like Glassfish, WebLogic and, to a lesser extent, Tomcat which is just a servlet/JSP container). If you're learning Spring, then follow the Spring tutorials. All you'll need are some jars to compile your code, all of which are available using Maven or Gradle, and Tomcat to deploy the built application.

Comment: So, in short, Java EE is not something you download. It doesn't replace the JDK. Java EE application are deployed in application servers, which are Java applications executed by the standard JDK/JRE.

Comment: Thanks for the straightforward answer. I was getting a bit of confused on this topic.

Comment: During a Spring course you was asked to download Java EE? How ridiculous. I seriously doubt the quality of that course.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to have a look here [Where to Download java-ee.jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358220/where-to-download-java-ee-jar)

As mentioned above Java EE is a specification and is itself a set of interfaces, simply no more than an API. The EE container vendor provides implementations.

You have also mentioned that you have Java SE before, and now you'll need a Java SDK.
In fact you'll need to update JAVA_HOME to SDK  folder. 
Also you can add %JAVA_HOME%/bin directory  to your PATH.
You don't need to introduce new ones, unless the tutorial say otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

neither you need to install windows variable nor to download java EE version.